# I want to extract a row element in a matrix

Tags: matlab

X =

```
 4     3
 8     3
```

I want to extract the element in each row of X and do some operation on each of them separably (4,3) and (8,3). however the size of may be different based on some parameters in my code, so I want general formula to do such thing, 
How I can use the for loop for solving this issue ?

Comment: Take a look at the `colon` operator. Type in `doc colon` to open the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This link shows how to extract specific lines (or columns) from a matrix http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

All you have to do is write a loop on an index `ii` to go through every line.

```
for ii=1:size(X,1)
     a=myfun(X(ii,:));
end
```